# A multi-input (text and numeric) model for regression giving same output

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, regression

I have a problem where I need to predict the number of clicks based on Date, CPC(cost per click), Market(US or UK) and keywords(average length 3-4 words, max 6). So the features that I decided to input the model were:

```
Day(1-31)  WeekDay(0-6)  Month(1-12)   US-Market(0 or 1)  UK-Market(0 or 1)   CPC(continuous numeric)
```

And the output is the continuous numeric Number of Clicks.

For Keywords I used keras tokenizer to convert to sequences and the padded those sequences. The I used the glove word embeddings and created an embedding matrix and fed to the nueral Network model as described [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/) in pretrained glove embeddings section.

The model that I used is:

[image]

The last Dense layer has linear activation. The model has two inputs (nlp_input for text data) and meta_input for (numerical,categorical data). Both models are concatenated after the Bidirectional LSTM to the nlp_input
The loss is :

```
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt,metrics=['acc'])
```

where `opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)`

I trained the model for 100 epochs and the loss was close to 8000 at that point.
But when I apply prediction to the test they result in the same number for all test inputs and that number is even negative `-4.5 * e^-5`. Could someone guide me as to how should I approach this problem and what improvements could I do to the model.